# How to add multiple divider view in a custom cell in UITableView IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, excel, uitableview

I have an iOS application in which I need to make my *tableView* looks
 like an excel sheet view.For that, I am trying to make a custom cell
 with multiple views as a divider. Here is  what I am trying to achieve

[image]

I am trying to add the views like this .But I need to add the auto
 layout constraints. Can anybody help me to set it correctly on the
 *tableView* cell?

Comment: Do you embed the separator views in the cell ? Using one for bottom and one for top?

Comment: use a collectionVIew.

Answer (score 0):

1) Put 6 `UIView's` inside cell. In which 4 are of `equal width constraint` and 2 are of `equal width constraint` as per image.

2) Take 5 divider view. It also has equal width constraint.

3) Also set the remain constrain like select 4 view's which are equal width and set `top,left,right` and `bottom` constraint. Same as other 2 view which are of equal width. Same for divider view's.

Answer (score 0):

try with UICollection View ... This will be perfect for your problem